# How to get the dockerTag label via the Artifactory API?

Tags: docker, build, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I am using Artifactory Version 4.16.0 and need to retrieve the **Docker Info Label** used to tag my image using the Artifactory API.

The label is definitely set as it appears in the Artifactory UI, under the Docker Info panel, in the Label key-value section.

Using the following API I can see the manifest.json

`curl -uadmin:pass https://artifacts.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/storage/my-docker-dev/my-component/my-image-1.0.0-1498449060`

but this does not contain the Docker Label I am after. I read the documentation, but cannot figure out how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access the build properties, which include the Docker labels, the name of the artefact must be followed by **/manifest.json?properties**

e.g.:
`curl -uadmin:pass https://artifacts.my-company.com/artifactory/api/storage/my-docker-dev/my-component/my-image-1.0.0-1498449060/manifest.json?properties`

returns something like

`{
  "properties" : {
    "docker.label.com.my-company.repository.commit.full" : [ "4fb524c0cb2139b15074b348bddb1952fa68deb1" ],
    "docker.label.com.my-company.repository.commit.short" : [ "4fb52" ],
    "docker.manifest" : [ "develop-1.0.0-1498449060" ],
    "docker.manifest.type" : [ "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" ],
    "docker.repoName" : [ "my-component" ],
    "sha256" : [ "0c8f855fbd7f6065972eec9a8ca7e48980f19sd3db07c47751bbe17043ddda4d" ]
  },
  "uri" : "https://artifacts.my-company.com/artifactory/api/storage/my-docker-dev/my-component/develop-1.0.0-1498449060/manifest.json"
}`